# OpenMP fastest way to update a struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, parallel-processing, openmp

In my code I have a lot of pieces where I have a double loop and I need to update values inside a struct. The problem is that it is an array of structs so there is a lot of dereferenciation going on. Here is an example:

```
    for(i=0;i<y;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<x;j++) {
                index = i*x+j;
                y1 = (i + 1) % y;
                x1 = (j + 1) % x;
                y2 = (i == 0) ? (i + y - 1) : (i - 1);
                x2 = (j == 0) ? (j + x - 1) : (j - 1);
                str[i *x + j].arr[0]  = c[index].arr[0];
                str[i *x + x1].arr[1] = c[index].arr[1]; 
                str[y1*x + j].arr[2]  = c[index].arr[2]; 
                str[i *x + x2].arr[3] = c[index].arr[3];
                str[y2*x + j].arr[4]  = c[index].arr[4]; 
                str[y1*x + x1].arr[5] = c[index].arr[5];
                str[y1*x + x2].arr[6] = c[index].arr[6];

            }
   }
```

I would like to speed this up as much as possible, maybe using OpenMP. I think there would be a lot of false sharing and I would not also be able to use pointers. Do you guys know an efficient way to speed this up (and similar codes)

Comment: Are you running on a multi-core system?

Comment: There are lots of little optimizations you can make, even without splitting things out to multiple cores, but it looks like you may already be aware of some of them.  One biggie is that C is inherently row-major in the way it stores array data.  Meaning that X[i][j] and X[i][j+1] are next to each other, while X[i][j] and X[i+1][j] are not, in fact can be very far away.  The take away is to make sure your indexing is accessing memory sequentially through the neighborhood, and not bouncing around the continents .

Comment: I am running it on an i7 but i am going to test it other machines as well. I tried to use pragma omp for with and without schedule and collapse. My average time is 10.4 seconds (minimum 10.20 and max 11). When i use pragma it slows down a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0;i<y;i++) {
    y1 = (i + 1) % y;
    y2 = i? i-1 : y-1;
    for(j=0;j<x;j++) {
        index = i*x+j;
        x1 = (j + 1) % x;
        x2 = j? j-1:x-1;
        str[i *x +  j].arr[0] = c[index].arr[0];
        str[i *x + x1].arr[1] = c[index].arr[1]; 
        str[y1*x +  j].arr[2] = c[index].arr[2]; 
        str[i *x + x2].arr[3] = c[index].arr[3];
        str[y2*x +  j].arr[4] = c[index].arr[4]; 
        str[y1*x + x1].arr[5] = c[index].arr[5];
        str[y1*x + x2].arr[6] = c[index].arr[6];

    }
}
```

I think there will be not so much of false sharing, because `str[]` is only read from and `c[]` seems well separated between threads (there should be little overlap of cache lines written into by different threads). Just try and time it. If it scales well, then false sharing is not an issue.

Comment: thanks. I get almost the same time with this change. So there isn't much i can do with the struct i guess.